# Cascading/dependent dropdown issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

So I have a two level cascading dropdowns in my application. Things work fine when I populate root dropdown and try to work with the second level to and fro, but suppose I have an element selected in my 2 level and I go and change the root dropdown value to default value (in my case "-- Select --") it throws null exception. I know it's because the linq for 2nd level doesn't find records for that value in root table. Can anyone suggest what should I do in such a scenario? However, this issue doesn't creep up when I change the root in the runtime to some other value from the database, the second level in this case populates with the changed set of value. Suggestions, please?

This is my query for reference:

```
var departmentsQuery = (from e in db.Batch
                        where e.U_BCode == id
                        select e.U_CCode).First();
var departmentsQuery1 = (from e in db.Class
                         where e.U_CCode == departmentsQuery
                         select e).ToList();
ViewBag.SelectedDepartment = new SelectList(departmentsQuery1, "U_CLCode", "U_CLName");
return Json(ViewBag.SelectedDepartment, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try using `FirstOrDefault()`, as it'll return `null` instead of throwing an exception:

```
var departmentsQuery1 = (from e in db.Class
                         where e.U_CCode == departmentsQuery
                         select e).FirstOrDefault();

if (departmentsQuery1 == null)
//return your default "--Select--" list
```